# Exposing custom property to visual studio designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am creating a custom button that is subclassed under usercontrol. I am trying to figure out how I can expose the enum property to the designer so I can set the enum when using the designer. What do I have to add so that the control's property shows up on the designer?

```
namespace App1
{
    public enum foodType
    {
        Appetizers,
        Breakfast,
        Lunch,
        Dinner,
        Desserts,
        Drinks
    };

    public sealed partial class FoodTypeButton : UserControl
    {
        public foodType type
        {
            get { return type; }
            set { type = value; }
        }
        public FoodTypeButton()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

The reason why I want to have this button have an enum is so that I can pass all 6 buttons to one method. This one method will check the enum and call the corresponding grid of buttons.

Right now I have

```
appetizerButtonClicked()
{
//call other grid
}

breakfastButtonClicked()
{
//call other grid
}

lunchButtonClicked()
{
//other grid
}
```

and so on....

Perhaps there is a better way to handle this?

Comment: Delete all that. Your data model (FoodType) does not belong into the UI. Create a proper ViewModel for whatever you're trying to do and leave the  UI alone.

Comment: @HighCore The only reason for the enum is that so I can pass it to one method instead of creating 5 different methods. And depending on that enum, it will display the corresponding grid of buttons. I'll update my question in a bit.

Comment: you have several misconceptions. First of all you don't "call"  the UI. What you need is  a TabControl. Second, again, your data model does not belong into the UI. Create a proper ViewModel and use proper DataBinding.

Comment: Thanks @HighCore!, I've been reading up on MVVM and I'm going to see if I can properly implement the correct design pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is showing for me in designer. Ensure you have added the property correctly. 
If my guess is correct, you would give the property definition wrongly. And it would throw the stackoverflow exception. In the sample code given, you have forgot to add the private member definition of property.

```
    private foodType type;
    public foodType Type
    {
        get { return type; }
        set { type = value; }
    }
```

now you can get the Type property in designer.